# VBA code stuck in doevents occasionally

Tags: vba, excel, import

My code is simple. It navigates different URLs for different worksheets and import two data from each of the URLs.

```
Public Sub import_Data()

Dim ie As InternetExplorer, htmlDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim price As String, volume As String
Dim sheet As Integer
Dim link(14), URL As String

'URL to navigate
link(1) = "https://hk.finance.yahoo.com/q?s=0017.HK&ql=0"
link(2) = "https://hk.finance.yahoo.com/q?s=0151.HK&ql=0"
link(3) = "https://hk.finance.yahoo.com/q?s=0267.HK&ql=0"
link(4) = "https://hk.finance.yahoo.com/q?s=0494.HK&ql=0"
link(5) = "https://hk.finance.yahoo.com/q?s=0700.HK&ql=0"
link(6) = "https://hk.finance.yahoo.com/q?s=0857.HK&ql=0"
link(7) = "https://hk.finance.yahoo.com/q?s=0883.HK&ql=0"
link(8) = "https://hk.finance.yahoo.com/q?s=0939.HK&ql=0"
link(9) = "https://hk.finance.yahoo.com/q?s=0992.HK&ql=0"
link(10) = "https://hk.finance.yahoo.com/q?s=1088.HK&ql=0"
link(11) = "https://hk.finance.yahoo.com/q?s=1398.HK&ql=0"
link(12) = "https://hk.finance.yahoo.com/q?s=1880.HK&ql=0"
link(13) = "https://hk.finance.yahoo.com/q?s=3328.HK&ql=0"
link(14) = "https://hk.finance.yahoo.com/q?s=3988.HK&ql=0"

Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = True

For sheet = 1 To 14
    Worksheets(sheet).Activate

'Go to different URL for different worksheets  
    URL = link(sheet)
    ie.navigate URL

    Do Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
       DoEvents
    Loop

    Set htmlDoc = ie.document

'pull two data from url  
    price = htmlDoc.getElementsByClassName("time_rtq_ticker")(0).innerText
    volume = htmlDoc.getElementsByClassName("yfnc_tabledata1")(9).innerText

    Cells(22, 2) = price
    Cells(22, 3) = volume

Next sheet

End Sub
```

The weird thing is that for each of the URLs, it can sometimes import the 2 data successfully, but sometimes it gets stuck in the "DoEvents" line.

What's wrong with the code? Why does it works sometimes but does not completely fail? Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: What references have you pick in *VBA > Tools > References* **??**

Comment: Besides those default setting, i have picked Microsoft HTML Object Library and Microsoft Internet Controls.

Answer (score 1):

I ran you code and it works fine............just VERY slowly.............the problem is that the code re-navigates over and over to `finance.yahoo` .......there is much junk in the site *(ads, etc)* that must be re-loaded over and over.

To speed this up:

- navigate to the site once
- use internet controls to direct IE to select the appropriate data *(just you would manually)*
- store that data just as you are doing now.

Comment: Thank you for your replay. It is really slow indeed... What I want to do is actually getting instant stock quote. I am quite new to VBA. Could you explain more on your three suggestion please?

Comment: @JJC .....I agree that it should be possible.............after all, if a cell phone can get instant info, why can't a computer **??**

Comment: By the way, I really get stuck on doevents. Normally, it can navigate 2 to 3 url or sometimes more than 10, but it can never run the full code. When I press break in the debugger, it stops at the doevents.